# Is there any easy way to generate sequencial IDs starting from one based on another ID using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have used Spring Boot's SequenceStyleGenerator to generate custom formatted IDs.
For example ORG0001, USR0001, VEH0001, etc. They work perfectly but independently.

I need to create a hierarchical ID flow like this.

The top of the hierarchy is Organization.
(Organization ID can be ORG0001. This can be achieved using Spring's SequenceStyleGenerator.)

Every other object ID's should automatically get its ID sequence number based on the organization. The first child object that relates to the organization must start from 1.

For Example, let's say, IDs of user objects and vehicle objects of each organization should start from 1 and continue. Like below.

```
ORG0001 - USR0001, USR0002, USR0003

        - VEH0001, VEH0002, VEH0003

ORG0002 - USR0001, USR0002

        - VEH0001, VEH0002, VEH0003
```

Any Clue is appreciated!

Comment: This seems like a better solution for FKs or OneToOne fields and multiple tables, where the pk of the ORG is the OneToOne relationship in USR and VEH so all can be logically grouped together. Without that I'm thinking you will need to setup presave logic to accommodate for your needs where you manually assign the values

Comment: @ViaTech Thanks for the valuable comment. Can you elaborate on your point a little bit, please?